# Is there a way to fix the 'Expected a step @ line' error from a jenkins file

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I created a very basic `jenkinsfile` to run run a maven project. I added a configuration to read from the project's pom.xml file during the build stage, but the build fails with the error: `Expected a step @ line 32`. This is the code on that line: `pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml`

I read on SO from some users that had a similar issue that the step should be enclosed in script{}, so I tried this, but I am still getting the same error. What am I doing wrong here:

```
pipeline {
agent any

options{
    timestamps()
}

stages {

    stage ('Compile Stage') {
        steps {
            script {
                pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'. //error is thrown here
                withMaven(maven: 'MAVEN_HOME') {
                    sh 'mvn clean install'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stage ('Testing Stage') {
        steps {
            withMaven(maven : 'MAVEN_HOME') {
                sh 'mvn test'
            }
        }
    }


    stage ('Cucumber Reports') {
        steps {
            cucumber buildStatus: "UNSTABLE",
                    fileIncludePattern: "**/cucumber.json",
                    jsonReportDirectory: 'target'
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
    Obtained Demo/jenkinsfile.groovy from git https://repo@bitbucket.org/my-repo/bitbucketfiles.git
    Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
    org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
    WorkflowScript: 32: Expected a step @ line 32, column 17.
                       pom = readMavenPom file: 'Demo/pom.xml'
                       ^
    
    1 error
    
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:571)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:523)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: First you have to check if you correctly installed `https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/` in your Jenkins. Second you seemed to misunderstand Maven concepts of Life cycle. If you `mvn clean install` then already all unit tests have run while having another step `mvn test` will repeat several steps. Furthermore  it usually does not make sense to use `mvn install` in such cases usually `mvn verify` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks@khmarbaise, but I am not sure what exactly I am looking for in the doc. Can you be more specific as to how to code that stage that reads from a pom.xml file?

Comment: You have to check if in Jenkins the pipeline utility steps plugin is installed because it does not look like but it could also be the case that you are doing it wrong (more likeley): `  pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'.` ... I would try `pom = readMavenPom("pom.xml")' (without the trailing `.`)... apart from that I would ask why do you need to read the pom file?

Comment: I already have the plugin installed. Also, pom.xml is not in the root directly. It's in Demo module, so I need the path Demo/pom.xml. Its a maven project, so Jenkins need to execute pom, otherwise, my test won't execute with a `mvn test`. I expect Jenkins to automatically detect pom.xml location, buts its not. I am getting the error:  `The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/jo/.jenkins/workspace/DeclarativePipelineDemo). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory`. How do I put pom on that path?

Comment: Can you confirm there is not a dot at the ending of `pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'.`

Comment: No dot at the end

Comment: Additionally, there appears to be an extra closing bracket `}` in the code.